# html and php form will not submit to email?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I've been trying to submit a form that is on my website but the form will not submit. I am not a php expert and I can not tell where my error is. The php file opens instead of sending to my two emails.

html

```
<form action="email.php" method="post" name="emailForm">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="Name"></label>
         <input  class="form-control name" placeholder="Name" id="Name" name="name">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="Email"></label>
         <input  class="form-control email" placeholder="Email" id="Email" name="email">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="Subject"></label>
         <input  class="form-control subject" placeholder="Subject" id="Subject" name="subject">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="Message"></label>
         <textarea  class="form-control Message" placeholder="Message" id="Message" name="message"></textarea>
     </div>
     <input type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-default button_submit"></input>
</form>
```

and I have the php file in the main directory
and it contains

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $email_from = "georgestcm@gmail.com";
    $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
    $email_subject = "New Form submission";

    $to = "georgestcm@gmail.com, yahwehown@gmail.com";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n"."Here is the message:\n $message".

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

?>
```

and my form validation is in in jquery. That is why I have not done it in php, because I am not a php expert.

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var name = $('input.name');
  var email = $('input.email').prop('disabled',true);
  var subject = $('input.subject').prop('disabled',true);
  var message = $('textarea.Message').prop('disabled',true);
  var button = $('input#button').prop('disabled',true);


  name.on('keyup',function() {
    if($(this).val().length > 0) {
      email.prop('disabled',false);
    } else {
      email.prop('disabled',true);
    }
  });

  email.on('keyup',function() {
    if($(this).val().length > 0 && $(this).val().includes('@') && $(this).val().includes('.com')) {
      subject.prop('disabled', false);
      message.prop('disabled',false);
    } else {
      subject.prop('disabled', true);
      message.prop('disabled',true);
      button.prop('disabled',true);
    }
  });

  message.on('keyup',function() {
    if($(this).val().length > 0){
      button.prop('disabled',false);
    }
  })

  button.on('click', function() {
    name.val('');
    email.val('');
    subject.val('');
    message.val('');
  }) 
})
```

I want to send email to my two emails.

Comment: Everything in email.php seems OK - are you sure the email.php file is in the same directory as the html page? Also, you say the php file opens - it sounds like the php form is not running on a server. Where exactly are the html and php files?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you getting an error, or is nothing happening?

Comment: _Side note:_ Even if you have input validation in your JS, you need to have it in your PHP as well. JS validations are not safe since anyone can bypass them by simply posting to your PHP directly.

Comment: The main directory has js/css and images and the main html files are outside of all of those. It opens the php file in a new page instead of actually  submitting to the email.

Comment: Check if there an error related to `mail()` by adding an [error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#121163)

Comment: What do you mean by "The php file opens" - is the source code of that file shown in your browser?

Comment: Please check if there is any javascript error in your browser console, that is definitely some bug in javascript. Also you email.php file should be in same folder where your html file is.

Comment: when the php file open, it opens in a new window and the scourse code is on the screen and no, theres no javacript errors and yes the php file is where my html file is